# Как при создании экземпляра собственного контейнерного класса в "<>" передать тип элементов

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

У меня задача: реализовать очередь как класс в C++. В конструкторе класса vector передаётся тип элементов, например, `vector <int> a`. Как мне также передать тип элементов в конструктор своего класса, например, `MyQueue <int> a`?

Comment: Писать шаблонный класс.

Comment: Тут тип элементов не передается в конструктор,  `vector<int>`  - это тип создаваемого объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего Ваш шаблонный класс будет выглядеть где то так

```
template <typename T>
class MyQueue
{

};
```

и такой класс уже можно использовать как Вам хочется

```
MyQueue<int> a;
```

другое дело, что этот класс ничего не делает:) Но это легко дописать. Если Ваш класс не должен делать чего то "сверхъестественного", то используем простое правило, везде, где нужен этот "тип с конструктора" (да, я знаю, что это неправильная формулировка, но это же короткий курс в шаблонные классы:) ), просто пишите `T` (это имя указанно в угловых скобках после typename).

Например, напишем заготовку для `push`

```
template <typename T>
class MyQueue
{
  std::vector<T> m_data; // где то же нужно это хранить
  public:
    void push(T el) { m_data.push_back(el); };
};
```

ну или так (если тип "большой", то его лучше передать по константной ссылке. А может даже стоит подумать о `std::move`).

```
void push(const T& el) { m_data.push_back(el); };
```

и теперь, когда Вы напишите `MyQueue<double> data;` будет сгенерировано где то такое

```
template <>
class MyQueue
{
  std::vector<double> m_data; // где то же нужно это хранить
  public:
    void push(double el) { m_data.push_back(el); };
};
```

теперь дописывайте функции, которые Вам нужны и готово.